# Length of the longest string passed as an argument

Tags: javascript, count, string-length

I can't seem to wrap my head around this. What i would like is a text box where input it 1234,12345, 12346 and return a integer of the longest string passed. So above would return 6.

I have the following Javascript code with a text box:

```
var titleInput = document.getElementById("textBoxValue");
function countString() 
  {
 var string = titleInput.value; // Does not work
 //var string = ["123", "1234"]; works with out text box returns 4 hard coded
 console.log(string); // returns ["123, 1234"]

 var largest = 0; // set largest to 0
 for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
   if (string[i].length > largest) {
     largest = string[i].length;

   }
}
 console.log(largest);
}
countString();
```

I don't understand why it works when hard coded but when submitting it from text box it doesn't.

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate the language you're working in.

Comment: are you using a preprocessor `document.getElementById(“text” BoxValue);` doesn't look like plain JS? Also I would avoid using variable name like `string` when `String` is a javascript native object

Comment: var titleInput = document.getElementById(“textBoxValue"); is what it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the functionality of the code, you have to split the value of the textbox into an array, using the split() method and use that as your "string" variable (avoid using reserved words for variable names!). Otherwise, with the string[i] statement, you would access the individual characters of the string, and not the actual substrings separated by commas. So your function should end up like this:

```
var titleInput = document.getElementById("textBoxValue");

function countString() {
var str = titleInput.value.split(',');
console.log(str);

var largest = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    if (str[i].length > largest)
        largest = str[i].length;
console.log(largest);
}

countString();
```

Comment: This worked as needed.  I have to remove the white spaces from the str, i don't want that it in the count.  Thanks for the explanation now my head is wrapped around it :)

Answer (score 2):

To get the array from the textbox, you can use

```
var titleInput = document.getElementById("text"),
    arr = titleInput.value.split(', ');
```

And to get the max length, you can use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) together with one of these

- ES5 [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

  ```
  arr.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      return Math.max(prev, curr.length)
  }, 0);
  ```
- ES5 [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

  ```
  Math.max.apply(null, arr.map(function(str){
      return str.length;
  }));
  ```
- ES5 [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), simplifying with ES6 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions):

  ```
  Math.max(...arr.map(str => str.length));
  ```

Comment: No explanation -> worthless! (What's ES6?...)

Comment: @Sam You can read the MDN articles I linked. ES6 is the new version of EcmaScript, currently only a draft, and with small browser support. It introduces amazing features which hopefully will be safe to use in few years.